# Just refreshing certain iframes without refreshing entire page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

When a page initially loads I have a hidden iframe and other visible ones.  Then when a button is clicked I need to hide one that was previously visible, then unhide another (actually I need to set the src attribute too on the one that is becoming visible, but I'll tackle that next).  I don't want to refresh the entire page (hence the return false below).

The code below does not display the red iframe2 upon the button click.  Can you tell me why?

```
<form>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <input type="submit" id="search" value="Search" />
</form>
<iframe id="frame0" style="background-color: blue" height="200" width="800" ></iframe>
<iframe id="frame1" style="background-color: yellow" height="200" width="800" ></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" style="visibility: hidden; background-color: red" height="200" width="800" ></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#search" ).click(function(event) {
        $("#frame1").hide();
        $("#frame2").show();
        $('#frame2')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

User `disply` insted of `visibility` edit, your `frame2` as below :

```
<iframe id="frame2" style="display: hidden; background-color: red" height="200" width="800" ></iframe>
```

Here is working jsfiddle :

[https://jsfiddle.net/keval/vqyczm7a](https://jsfiddle.net/keval/vqyczm7a/)

Comment: thx but didn't work.  frame2 is displayed at initial page load now.  This is on chrome.

Comment: i have tested on chrome itself, share your complete code

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.show() and`.hide() work with the CSS display property, as oppose to the visibility property.

`.show()` = `css('display', 'block')` 
`.hide()` = `css('display', 'none')`

However, you can use `.toggle()` to either hide or show an element based on it's current state. I think this is what you would require, as you'd like to hide the one that was previously visible.

You'd need to change your `iframe` visibility style to use display instead

```
<iframe id="frame2" style="display: none; background-color: red" height="200" width="800" ></iframe>
```

Then instead of showing and hiding the iframes, use `.toggle()`

```
$( "#search" ).click(function(event) {
    $("#frame1").toggle();
    $("#frame2").toggle();
    $('#frame2')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
    return false;
});
```

See my working example: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/14250/

Answer (score 0):

In Basic

**Same Origin - Iframe**

```
document.getElementById('frame2').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

**Different Origin - Iframe**

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame2');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

In Angular

**HTML**

```
<iframe
        [id]="iFrameId"
        [src]="data.iFrameUrl | safe"
        width="100%"
        height="640"
      ></iframe>
      <div class="vidyard-section" *ngIf="vidyard">
        <a
          class="vidyard-card"
          href="#"
          target="_self"
          [attr.rel]="undefined"
          (click)="onClickCard($event, clip)"
          *ngFor="let clip of videoClips[0]?.clips"
        >
```

**Typescript**

```
onClickCard(evt: any, clip: any) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (this.isBrowser) {
      (this.dom.querySelector('iframe') as HTMLElement).setAttribute(
        'src',
        this.iframePath + clip.id
      );
    }
  }
```